# Apigee Fetch WSDL Error Could not download resource peer not authenticated

Tags: apigee

**First**

*Issue:*
Not able to add new API Proxy by importing existing SOAP WSDL

*Error:*
Fetch WSDL Error: Could not download resource. peer not authenticated

*My view:*
I suspect is caused by WSDL structure contains import XSD which derived from another link.

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://XXX/message" schemaLocation="https://XXX:123/xxxservices/XxxWebService?xsd=1"/>
```

Tried modifying my WSDL , instead of using import from external URL, I copied the whole XSD structure into the WSDL. It works!

***Question:***
What is the issue behind the validation process? f.y.i. I have also imported the certificate into my Java truststore (cacerts)

**Second**

*Issue:* 
Few elements/parameters not populated after successfully imported the WSDL

*Portion of my WSDL :*

```
<xs:complexContent>
  <xs:extension base="ns:UserDetailsRequest">
    <xs:sequence>

<xs:extension base="ns:UserDetailsRequest">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="userID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
 </xs:sequence>
```

*My view:*

I found out that the Apigee does not populate the parameters of password and userID, I suspect the issue is caused by implementing XML extension base component

***Question:***

How to solve the missing parameters issue?

Thank you!

My whole WSDL is below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/" name="XyzWebService">
<definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/" name="XyzWebService">
<types>  
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/message" schemaLocation="https://www.xxx.com:123/docxservices/XyzWebService?xsd=1" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/" schemaLocation="https://www.xxx.com:123/docxservices/XyzWebService?xsd=2" />
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="docUpload">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:docUpload" />
</message>
<message name="docUploadResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:docUploadResponse" />
</message>
<portType name="XyzWebServicePortType">
<operation name="docUpload">
<input message="tns:docUpload" />
<output message="tns:docUploadResponse" />
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="XyzWebServicePortTypePortBinding" type="tns:XyzWebServicePortType">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />
<operation name="docUpload">
<soap:operation soapAction="" />
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="XyzWebService">
<port name="XyzWebServicePortTypePort" binding="tns:XyzWebServicePortTypePortBinding">
<soap:address location="https://www.xxx.com:123/docxservices/XyzWebService" />
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

1st XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.3-07/10/2008 08:41 PM(bt).-->
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/message" xmlns:xns="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/message" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:complexType name="DocumentUserDetailsRequest">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="userID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="DocumentResponseStatus">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="errorDetailsMap">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="key" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="value" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="success" type="xs:boolean"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="DocumentUploadRequest">
<xs:complexContent>
  <xs:extension base="xns:DocumentUserDetailsRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="docName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="folderName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="DocumentUploadResponse">
<xs:complexContent>
  <xs:extension base="xns:DocumentResponseStatus">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="docNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="docName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

2nd XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.3-07/10/2008 08:41 PM(bt).-->
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/" xmlns:xns="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/" xmlns:ns1="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/message" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:import namespace="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/message" schemaLocation="XyzWebService.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="docUpload" type="xns:docUpload"/>
<xs:element name="docUploadResponse" type="xns:docUploadResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="docUpload">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="arg0" type="ns1:DocumentUploadRequest" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="arg1" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="docUploadResponse">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="return" type="ns1:DocumentUploadResponse" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Can you provide a URL to your WSDL?

Comment: Hi Randy,

Thanks for the response.

I have attached the WSDL portion above , sorry not able to give you the url link due to compliance issue

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer - I 'm just posting it here so you can read it.

Your original imports look fine to me and *should* be supported.

I took your files, and gave them valid import references (they were still referencing and external server) and everything worked when I tried it, so I'm going to need your original hosted WSDL, XSDs to better diagnose the issue.  Is that possible?

File contents:

WSDL

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/" name="XyzWebService">
<types>  
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/message" schemaLocation="XyzWebService1.xsd" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/" schemaLocation="XyzWebService2.xsd" />
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="docUpload">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:docUpload" />
</message>
<message name="docUploadResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:docUploadResponse" />
</message>
<portType name="XyzWebServicePortType">
<operation name="docUpload">
<input message="tns:docUpload" />
<output message="tns:docUploadResponse" />
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="XyzWebServicePortTypePortBinding" type="tns:XyzWebServicePortType">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />
<operation name="docUpload">
<soap:operation soapAction="" />
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="XyzWebService">
<port name="XyzWebServicePortTypePort" binding="tns:XyzWebServicePortTypePortBinding">
<soap:address location="https://www.xxx.com:123/docxservices/XyzWebService" />
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

XyzWebService1.xsd

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.3-07/10/2008 08:41 PM(bt).-->
    <xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/message" xmlns:xns="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/message" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="DocumentUserDetailsRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="userID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="DocumentResponseStatus">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="errorDetailsMap">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="key" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element name="value" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="success" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="DocumentUploadRequest">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="xns:DocumentUserDetailsRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="docName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="folderName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="DocumentUploadResponse">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="xns:DocumentResponseStatus">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="docNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="docName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
```

XyzWebService2.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.3-07/10/2008 08:41 PM(bt).-->
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/" xmlns:xns="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/" xmlns:ns1="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/message" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:import namespace="http://webservice.docx.abc.com/message" schemaLocation="XyzWebService.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="docUpload" type="xns:docUpload"/>
<xs:element name="docUploadResponse" type="xns:docUploadResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="docUpload">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="arg0" type="ns1:DocumentUploadRequest" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="arg1" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="docUploadResponse">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="return" type="ns1:DocumentUploadResponse" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Below are the URL link, this service has been officially opened to public.

https://www.tradexchange.gov.sg/docxservices/DocxWebService?wsdl

If you see carefully. when you import the WSDL, not all parameters are populated in the REST API Parameters. e.g. userID and password parameters are missing.


The other issue I encounter 'peer not authenticated' . This might be due to 'self-signed' cert as I am executing service from test environment (but didn't happen for prod mode as the given link above). May I know if Apigee will use Java truststore in my machine to validate against the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Although you have your domains redacted, I notice you have a port number :123 on your resource:

```
https://www.xxx.com:123/docxservices/XyzWebService?xsd=1
```

Assume that all resources need to be reachable by Amazon AWS servers and that odd ports might be blocked. So if your https resource isn't on 443 it may be a problem for the Apigee system to connect to it.